# ios localize app display name does not work

Tags: ios, localization

I am implementing localization function for my app, and everything works fine except the app display name under the icon. My info.Plist is as:
[image]

I tried to remove the Bundle display nmae and bundle name and it also did not work.

My localization string file is like:
[image]

[image]

Anyone can help me with this? I have no idea what I did wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To localize the app name you should create a InfoPlist.Strings file as apple explains [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) in "Localizing the Information Property List Files" section. Then you just need to define the keys CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName as you already are doing.

Comment: Many thanks, it works now.
I have another question, I have many localized strings in app, some displayed correctly, but some are not, do you have any clue?

Comment: What happens when they were not displayed correctly?